# Where would you smell the extensive use of cigarettes in the cockpit of an A321?

Tags: safety, airlines, crew

Last night I flew on a A321 and midway during the 2.5hrs flight I went to the rear right toilet. It strongly smelt like hefty cigarette smell, but not like anybody would have smoked in there. I had the impression that the smell came out of the airvent. The cabin attendants sitting in the galley and chatting just a metre away must have noticed it, but did not react. Could used air from the cockpit get back there?

Comment: What makes you think it came from the cockpit? The rear lavatory is far away from the cockpit (about as far as you can possibly get).

Answer (score 1):

Far more logical would be that somebody smoked in the rear *left* toilet and that the vents for the two toilets are closely connected. There are all kinds of special rules, smoke detectors, fire extinguishers, etc. (varies by plane, but I've seen mention of this stuff many times) for airplane restrooms due to the non-zero chance that nicotine-addicted smokers on a long flight will try to light up in the one place where nobody can see them.

On the other hand, while pilots do have a lot more freedom to do what they want, including smoke, than everyone else on a plane, professional requirements (you need both hands when things get busy in the cockpit) and a healthy respect for the risk of smoke (from a fire, not from a cigarette, but plenty of fires have started from a cigarette) and fire on an airplane make me think that is rather unlikely in the cockpit of an airliner.

As far as the cabin attendants not noticing it, it is quite possible that they *did* notice it, but unless they found the smoking <s>gun</s> cigarette, there isn't much they can do during a flight.